# Making multiple layers editable in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, editing

I am using QGIS and I want to eliminate fields from 300 shapefiles.

All layers are loaded and selected.

Is there a way to enable all 300 for simultaneous editing?

Comment: Which software are you using, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code in the **Python Console** which iterates through each loaded layer (regardless if they're selected or not) and deletes the field with the name you specify. Just replace `field_name` with...a field name:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    with edit(layer):
        fields = layer.pendingFields()
        idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('field_name') 
        layer.dataProvider().deleteAttributes([idx])
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use this and report back.   Extreme newbie question:  "How can I find this post as it gets further down the list...?"

Comment: @buyukcam - I strongly advise that you take a look at [tour guide](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) (don't worry, it's quick!). It helps you understand more how this and other Stack Exchange forums work. You can also find everything that you post (questions/answers/comments etc) in [your profile](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/68778/buyukcam) by clicking your avatar icon at the top of the web page next to your repuation amount =)